# getting my reducer data to route component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I have a Root component which has all the routes of my application like so:

```
export class Root extends Component {
 static propTypes = {
     store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
 };
 render() {
   const { store } = this.props
   const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)
   history.listen(location => store.dispatch(addHistory(location)))
   return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/" component={Landing}/>
        <Route component={Main} >
         <Route path="/selfRegistration" component={SelfRegistrationForm}/>
         <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
         <Route path="/aboutus" component={AboutUs} />
         <Route path="/help" component={UserHelp} />
```

and I want some base data which I get from an ajax call to be populated in all the routes. I have stored the data in a reducer called dataReducer.

I want to pass the data as a prop to all my routes, but when I connect my redux state to the Root component like so:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
 return {
  langData: state.languageText
 }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Root)
```

I get the follwoing warnings:

****warning.js?85a7:35 Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.**

**browser.js?b253:49 Warning: [react-router] You cannot change ; it will be ignored****

I know the connect is again adding data to an already configured router with store which might be hampering everything. But what is the standard way of doing this.

**I just want access to the languageText reducer in this Root Component.**

Thank you

Comment: Show us your component, and the render method specifically

Comment: my component is Root which I have added in the question.

Comment: You are connecting `Root` component to a `Provider` that is **inside** the component itself.

Comment: aah got it. Have used redux subscribe function now. WIll update once I find the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was silly of me to try to wire it like this. But since it was a third party architecture, hence could not change the component tree.

I have instead used subscribe function of the store to get the languageText Reducer data. My code now is :

```
export default class Root extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.currentLangValue = {};
  this.handleDataChange = this.handleDataChange.bind(this);
 }
 static propTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
 };
 handleDataChange(store) {
 let previousValue = this.currentLangValue;
 this.currentLangValue = store.getState().languageText;
 if (previousValue != this.currentLangValue) {
   console.log(this.currentLangValue,'asjdhgsadasjdabsadhasdb');
 }
}
render() {
  const { store } = this.props;
  const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)
  store.subscribe(() => this.handleDataChange(store))
  history.listen(location => store.dispatch(addHistory(location)))

  return (
   <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" render={() => { <Landing props={this.currentLangValue}/> }} />
      <Route component={Main} >
        <Route path="/selfRegistration" component={SelfRegistrationForm}/>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
```